# referer-parser Golang: Production setting instead of using placeholder value?

Tags: go, http-referer

`referer-parser` read placeholder value in the example, while the production setting is not documented.

I need `referer-parser` to read real referer value instead of placeholder value.

Below is my code (the `referer_url` read placeholder value):

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/labstack/echo"
    "github.com/snowplow/referer-parser/go"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    e := echo.New()

    referer_url := "http://www.google.com/search?q=gateway+oracle+cards+denise+linn&hl=en&client=safari"
    r := refererparser.Parse(referer_url)

    e.Get("/users", func(c *echo.Context) *echo.HTTPError {
        return c.String(http.StatusOK, "The search term is: "+r.SearchTerm)
    })

    e.Run(":4444")
}
```

Comment: what "real referer value" are you trying to read? What do you want to do?

Comment: I mean, I need `referer-parser` to read real value instead of placeholder. Please read carefully the codes. In production, we need to change the placeholder value.

Comment: Are you asking how to read `referer_value` from some type of configuration, so you can replace it at runtime?

Comment: Get from the HTTP header. When someone come from Bing or Yahoo, I can get the HTTP referer data like referer URL & referer keyword

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the value you want from the http headers inside your handler:

```
e.Get("/users", func(c *echo.Context) *echo.HTTPError {
    refererURL := c.Request.Header.Get("Referer")
    r := refererparser.Parse(refererURL)
    return c.String(http.StatusOK, "The search term is: "+r.SearchTerm)
})
```